# Fetching SObject Id from changes in Lookup fields using History tracking

Tags: soql, custom-object, custom-field, lookup, sobject

I have set history tracking for my Custom Object and set a **Lookup** field for my referenced Object.

> **CustomObjectX_*c[Field1,Field2,Account*_c]**

Here **Account__c** is a lookup field to the Salesforce Account Object.

Whenever there is any change in Account_*c it reflects back in **CustomObjectX***_History with two entries.

Say old Account_*c is 001ABC (named A1)and new Account*_c is 001XYZ (named A2).

**entry1 for Account.Id:**

- OldValue: 001ABC
- NewValue: 001XYZ
- Field/Event: Account__c

**entry2 for Account.Name:**

- OldValue: A1
- NewValue: A2
- Field/Event: Account__c

**Problem:**

- Since the Field/Event is same in both these records it is hard to
  distinguish which maps to Account.Id and which maps to Account.Name.
- Currently I am querying back the Salesforce with each NewValue to
  check whether an Account with that Id exits.

**check for entry 1:**

```
SELECT id from Account where id = '001XYZ' => true
```

**check for entry 2:**

```
SELECT id from Account where id = 'A2' => false
```

Is there a smarter way to prevent Account.Name records being mixed up with the History Tracking ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly a with pleasure +1 on the quality of your question!

Yes it seems a shame to have to query the database to check this. The following use of [Id.valueOf](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Id_valueOf.htm) might be preferable for you? Though does assume your users are not naming Accounts with valid Id's, which would be bizzare i agree. That said something you could write a trigger validation on to be safe.

```
Boolean isId = true; // Think possitive thoughts!
try { 
    Id.valueOf(newValue);
} catch (Exception e) { isId = false; }
System.debug('Was it an Id? ' + isId);
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Sorry I missed out a point that I am consuming this data through REST API outside the scope of Apex. I tried these approaches 1) if some_random_text.starts_with('001') #=> likely to be AccountId 2) Changing Account__c type from Lookup to Master-Detail (works the way I want but this doesn't allow me to edit the field after creation) 3) order by Parent.LastModifiedDate and pick the second record with Field => 'Account__c' #=> seems Id record gets created before the Name. But I think if there is a way to stop the creation in the first place it would be great.

Comment: I moved away from my initial Reverse Lookup Query approach, since its really bad for my scenario(with REST API) due to two reasons 1. Costs me Additional API limit usage. 2. Processing delay due to Network request-response cycle (I felt this to be an overkill just for validation).

Comment: a regex would do a decent job of detecting an id, `[A-Za-z0-9]{18}`